# Deploy application with accord.video.ffmpeg c#

Tags: c#, deployment, ffmpeg, accord.net

I'm using accord.video.ffmpeg 3.4.0, downloaded via nuget,  to save a video with videorecorder class. If I compile (x86) my solution the application is running smoothly in visual studio, instead if I publish the app (same architecture ) when I try to run the setup.exe it installs the program but suddenly crashes. The problem is in the constructor of a class when I do new videorecorder(). It is like If during the deployment process not all the libraries needed are included.
Anyonw knows which libraries are missing?
Thank,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are not including the FFMPEG .dll files together with the .exe of your application when you are distributing it.

If you have installed the framework through NuGet, the package should have installed a .targets in your .csproj files that copies those .dlls to your project's output folder on every build.

Those .dll files are currently (as of Accord.NET 3.6.0) called:

- avcodec-57.dll
- avdevice-57.dll
- avfilter-6.dll
- avformat-57.dll
- avutil-55.dll
- postproc-54.dll
- swresample-2.dll
- swscale-4.dll

And can be found either in your output directory if it was automatically copied, or in the directory `packages\Accord.Video.FFMPEG.x.x.x` inside your solution folder.

Comment: This fixed my initial issue but not I get a different error:  "A type initializer for 'Module' threw an exception".  I think it's still complaining about the dll's